# PyRo and python

Tags: python, pyro

I use PyRo in my python programm. And I have a problem. class B: In callFromProxy print 0, but in callfun print right value = 10. Why? How to fix?

```
class A(Pyro.core.ObjBase):
 # set link to item class B
 def set(self, real_B):
  self.item_B = real_B

 # call function callfun in item_B
 def callfun(self):
  self.item_B.callfun(10)

class B(Pyro.core.ObjBase):
 # init class B
 def __init__(self):
  self.elements = {"name":0}

 # set proxy to item class A
 def set(self, proxyA):
  self.proxyA = proxyA

 # print
 def printvalue(self):
  print self.elements["name"]

 # call from proxy
 def callFromProxy(self):
  self.proxyA.callfun()
  self.printvalue() # this is not print 10, print 0

 # call function
 def callfun(self, value):
  self.elements["name"] = value
  self.printvalue() # but this is print 10

itemA = A()

# proxyA connect from PyRo to itemA

itemB = B()
itemB.set(itemA)

itemA.set(itemB)

itemB.callFromProxy() # this is not print 10
```

Comment: I fixed a few lines that I assumed were typos in your code.

Comment: I just tested the code above using the latest Pyro version and it works exactly as a I expected - it prints 10 twice. If I understand your post, this what you want.

Comment: Hi. I'm totally not sure what were you trying to do here, but if I understand you right - you set itemA to a proxy object, and itemB is left intact, i.e. it is a regular instance of class B right?

If it is, then what happens in your code, is that basically you make a copy of an object itemB references to, send it to server, modify it on server, and then print out the state of another object, which was originally created on client side, and which is not changed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe (and correct me if I'm wrong) PyRo uses asynchronous calls, at least by default.

So when you call `callFromProxy`, `printvalue` might get executed before `callfun` on `itemB`, because it takes time to call `A.callfun` and `B.callfun`. If/when this happens, `elements["name"]` will still be 0 when `printvalue` is called for the first time.

Comment: if I add time.sleep(5) before printvalue() in B.callFromProxy(), the result will not change. But request was complited...

Comment: hmm. beats me then, I never used PyRo, my answer was just an educated guess.